# Extracting text for internationalization

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

I currently have a ASP .NET MVC solution which I would like to internationalize. What tools are there to extract all text strings from project files?

I would probably need to write a parser to extract text strings from .cs, .js, .aspx, .ascx files but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're asking about extracting string literals from these files, I've occasionally come across some tools that claim to do this, though I've never tried them myself. I think ReSharper, "Resource Refactoring Tools", and probably others advertise about this, though how effective they are at it I don't know (or whether they can even target ".js" files). Shouldn't be hard to quickly find out though. Using an automated tool would still require that you manually assign a meaningful name to each string resource. You can also just search these files for string literals if you want and manually move them into ".resx" files yourself. Apply the :q regular expression in Visual Studio for instance (when searching). For ".aspx" and ".ascx" files though, you wouldn't need to do this for any strings that were assigned to your ASP.NET control properties. Visual Studio can already do it for you via "Generate Local Resource" on the "Tools" menu. See this in my article cited above or just Google for it. In any case, once your strings are in ".resx" files (if that's where you're planning to put them), then my own app will now kick in (allowing you to extract your resx strings into a single file for sending to a translator and later import the translated strings back into your solution).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you were using MVC so "Generate Local Resource" isn't so cut-and-dry. See here for starters: http://www.guysmithferrier.com/post/2009/05/Localizing-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper allows you to click on harcoded text and move it to resource files... but it is a manual process.